# Xamarin FCM Topic Subscription

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm developing an Android + iOS app using Xamarin Studio, I recently integrated the notification management system via Firebase, but I'm having some problems in the subscription of the topic, I'll explain to the Android app I've configured everything correctly, because if sending a notification to the segment of Android users through the dashboard Firebase app registers and receives properly, then I have added to MainActivity this line:
FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic ( "news");
within a "Task.Run (() =>" and before the call to the "LoadApplication" method of Forms

Then when I compile and start the application output is written: "[FirebaseInstanceId] topic sync succeeded"
But when I log in to the dashboard Firebase to make a message sending test in a topic, when I go to select the "Topics" is written: "This project has no arguments"

I wanted to ask if you could direct me on what may depend on what?
And how do you solve?
Maybe I need to include some other permission nell'AndroidManifest?
Or it must first ensure that even the iOS project subscribes the same topic Android?
Or maybe there are other things that I do and who currently do not know that you can tell me?

Thank you very much in advance.

For clarity and precision below carry the configuration for Firebase nell'AndroidManifest.xml I entered under the node "

```
<receiver 
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" 
        android:exported="false" />
    <receiver 
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" 
        android:exported="true" 
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I also want to clarify that I have inserted in the project the "google-services.json" file by selecting as BuildOptions -> "GoogleServicesJson"

Instead, the version of the package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging I'm using in the project is the "32.961.0"

Thanks again in advance to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may take a few hours (up to possibly a day) for the topic you recently subscribed a client to to show up in the Firebase Notifications Console.

What you could do for the meantime is to send the message to the topic either by [using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309674/fcm-with-postman-the-request-was-missing-an-authentication-key-fcm-token/45310143#45310143) or [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664911/firebase-cloud-messaging-send-click-action/44665817#44665817)

Answer (score 0):

For me Xamarin.Android :

code to subscribe topic:

```
FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic(topicName);
```

and when sent via firebase console notification receives within 5 minutes.

But I still don't know how topic subscription works in Xamarin iOS.